# Undefined variable in blade file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am beginner in Laravel and web development.
I have this code in blade file:

```
@foreach($plates as $value)
                                            @if ($value->type == 1)
                                                <div class="form-group row">
                                                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 text-right pt-2">
                                                        <input type="checkbox"
                                                               class="xxxxxx mr-2"
                                                               name="plate-ch-{{$value->id}}"  @if(old('plate-ch-'.$value->id, $selectedProductFeatures['plate-ch-'.$value->id])) checked @endif
                                                               value="1" >
                                                        <label>{{ $value->name }}</label>
                                                    </div>
                                                   
                                                </div>
                                            @endif
                                        @endforeach
```

I have error:

```
Undefined variable: selectedProductFeatures (View: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/roelle/resources/views/admin/products/view.blade.php)
```

This is wrong line:
name="countertop-ch-{{$value->id}}"  @if(old('countertop-ch-'.$value->id, $selectedProductFeatures['countertop-ch-'.$value->id])) checked @endif

I have a universal template for adding and editing a product.

How can I repair it?

Comment: check where $selectedProductFeatures should be defined. its telling you the variable is empty

Comment: in controller before send `$selectedProductFeatures` use `dd()` to find out what are you sending to blade.  `dd($selectedProductFeatures);`

Comment: Please, add you controller method to check where you defined `$selectedProductFeatures`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the variable $selectedProductFeatures from the controller into the view